# Even though I added .jar of JAI to Eclipse buildpath , getting "JAI cannot be resolved" error

Tags: java, eclipse, jai

**I'm new to java.**

I am trying to use Java Advanced Imaging to read an Image file as explained in here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/iio-141084.html

```
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import javax.media.jai.JAI;

public class ImageGetterJAI {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //image source
    String imagedir = "C:\\Users\\Emre\\Desktop\\Image\\Grass.tif";

    //get the image
    RenderedImage image = JAI.create("imageload", imagedir);
}
}
```

But I get JAI cannot be resolved error. Am I doing a fundamental mistake.

Screenshot of the project is below, hope this helps.

[image: Image of the project]

Comment: make sure you have your jar in your classpath, btw what is the error? screenshots?

Comment: I have added the screenhsot. Jar is in the build path. Is it same thing with the classpath, I will check immediately.

Comment: Do a project clean. If that does not help close your eclipse and reopen. And lastly remove the import and do the import again. Happens once ina while in eclipse. Project clean should help.

Comment: I have used another .jar file for JAI that I have found on the internet and done a project clean and it seems to fixed the "JAI cannot be resolved error". However, there are other errors now.